# Time formatting ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, time, formatting

I have a label in the grid whose value is populated from a dropdown in a popup window(The dropdown has time values in hours - 00 to 23). I have bound the label in the grid like so.

`<asp:Label ID="lblFromTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromTime", "{0:hh/mm}")%>'></asp:Label>`

The problem is when I select 13 from the dropdown(anything greater than 12 for that matter), it is populating as **01-00** rather than **13-00**.

How do I display the value as **13-00**?

**EDIT:**

When I change the label like

`<asp:Label ID="lblFromTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromTime", "{0:HH/MM}")%>'></asp:Label>`

and select **13** from my dropdown, it displays the text as **13-04**.

Comment: MM is for month and mm is for minutes. Try Jack's answer below. That should do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the format to:

```
"{0:HH/mm}"
```

So for example:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFromTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromTime", "{0:HH/mm}")%>'></asp:Label>
```

Capital `HH` is the key.

This is a good [TimeFormatting](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/206348/12-24-Hour-Time-format) reference